# What is the easiest way to open such a project in Android Studio? (and have it launch!)

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, import, gradle

Project in question is this, but it is a problem I've come across too often. Many projects seem to have a similar structure.
https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView

So again, I would like to know the quickest way to import/open the demo in this project **(and have it launch)** in the latest version of Android Studio.

I have tried importing the overall folder, tried importing the demo folder, but after battling with error after error for hours (in total time spent on getting projects like these to launch) I find it quicker to just create a new project and pull in all the files and resources one by one.

A step by step would be nice, if that's not asking for too much.

Comment: If the project you want to import is not a gradle project then in my opinion the best and fastest method to import is ,The way you have done .

Comment: @sunilsunny the aforementioned project **is** a gradle project though, isn't it?

Comment: Are you using that as a library  ?

Comment: @sunilsunny no, just would like to open it to see the demo

Comment: I will try this project my self and let you know if I met with any errors .

Comment: @sunilsunny Hey thanks for that. I have just got it to work - this one wasn't too difficult. I'll write up an answer for others struggling with this.

Comment: @ Alexandre GI got it working but I think they used an old version of android studio to build it ,resulted in this much errors. :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so this one wasn't too difficult. The key was using **Import project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc.)** or **Check out project from VC** as opposed to **Open project**.

After that there are a few errors that aren't too difficult but still very confusing for someone starting with Gradle, so here's how to fix them.
This is with the **Import Project** flow:

1. Import Project -> Select the overall folder -> OK.
2. First error I get is this:
   [image: Unsupported version of Android Gradle plug-in]
   This one's easy - click fix plugin link and that's done.
3. Next error: `The SDK Build Tools revision (19.0.3) is too low for project ':demo'. Minimum required is 19.1.0`

On the left you see Android view which hides the files you need when the project is not gradle-synced:

[image: Android project view]

Click Android dropdown (top left on the screenshot) and choose Project or Project files. Expand until you see these three build.gradle files:

[image: The three build.gradle files]

The demo > build.gradle and library > build.gradle are per module files. The other one is the project file.

So to get rid of the error change the buildToolsVersion (can be done with a quickfix alt+enter) to "19.1" in both per module build.gradle files.

And then "Try again" to resync the gradle project.

4. Last error is: `Error:(18, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'runProguard()'`

In v.1 of the android gradle plugin they have [changed](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-to-1-0-0) runProguard to minifyEnabled, so just change one to the other in the libary > build.gradle, resync, and the project should launch.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly import the project via GitHub/Git/Mercurial/SVN  from Quick Start.

[image]

Otherwise, go to File > New > Project from Version Control and then choose the version control you are using.

Comment: If it was this simple I wouldn't be asking. In the question I ask how to open it and **have it launch**. So I get these errors if I try to open it depending on what gradle wrapper option I choose: http://goloskok.com/u/2015-07-03_15-36-19.jpg
http://goloskok.com/u/2015-07-03_15-37-37.jpg And I've figured out before how to fix these individual errors, but they don't end there, which leads to my question or what is the quickest way to do this, because the errors are different depending on how you open it. Surely I am not the only one trying to open GitHub projects?

Answer (score 0):

In Your Case I would say you choose "Use default gradle wrapper" and studio automatically solve your gradle issues.

Comment: Not quite the case: http://www.goloskok.com/u/2015-07-03_15-36-19.jpg And after you do fix it, has other errors

Comment: you are using old version of gradle.Android studio gives this error to force developer to update to latest gradle and studio.Use this in you projects build.gradle                                                                                               buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}

Comment: **UPDATED**
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}